# Spring Initialized Properties using propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer referred from another project

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have a mvn project packaged as applicationConfig.jar that contains commonly shared properties across different other projects (WAR's(web application eg: application.war) and JAR's(batch eg: applicationBatch.jar)).

I have used propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer using annotation to initialize these properties in my applicationConfig.jar

This applicationConfig.jar is now added as dependency in pom.xml's for application.war & applicationBatch.jar

1) The java code in application.war is able to access properties initialized by code executed in applicationConfig.jar on server startup property. No issues here.

2) The applicationBatch.jar which is run from command line on linux machine, is unable to access properties. It appears like the properties initialization code is never executed, when the applicationBatch.jar is run.

Can anyone please help how can i ensure, code sitting in Jar file (applicationConfig.jar responsible for initializing properties using propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer), is executed, when a batch jar (applicationBatch.jar) is run from command line.

Code Snippet Below:

applicationConfig.jar:
[Attachment ][1]

[Property referenced using annotation and property from properties file][2]

Comment: Please share code snippet, especialy how do you reference  these properties.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot: Added the code snippet for applicationConfig.jar in my above question itself. This is just added as a dependency in

1) WAR pom.xml --> Works fine, able to execute applicationConfig.jar on startup.
2) JAR pom.xml ---> Unable to execute in my applicationConfig.jar

I access these initialized properties using Spring Value annotation for each of the properties from a constants file

Comment: could you include this snippet into your question? (brace button). If I understand correctly, `getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is never called when running `applicationBatch`?

Comment: Actually i cannot paste the code snippet, because am working on a remotemachine using citrix client. So attached screenshot

And yes, getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is never getting called when running applicationBatch (run from command line), but it perfectly runs when i start my server containing webapps (application.war).

Comment: Are you importing the configuration with the [`@Import`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) annotation for both your runtime ?

Comment: attached screenshot for property file content and how it is referenced in code in both runtimes.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, i no need to import that applicationconfig.jar code in both run times. When i added jar as dependency 

1) For WAR file, the code present in JAR is getting executed and properties are loaded

2) For JAR file, the code is never executed and properties are never loaded.

apologies if i dint get u right.

Comment: My question is malformed. Are you importing the `InternalConfig` configuration with an `@Import` annotation for both your runtime ? Or the corollaire: How have you configured Spring so that it loads `InternalConfig` ?

Comment: I got you... No i have not imported it in either of the runtimes. Just because its annotated as Configuration, i was thinking, Spring is taking care of running the code in getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() method, considering this file as an applicationContext.

So it worked fine for WAR, on server startup, without getting referenced from anywhere, it was able to call getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer 

But its not the case when am running my applicationBatch.jar

Comment: It will take care if you import `InternalConfig` using `@Import` or have configured component scan with a base package parent of the `InternalConfig` one.  Are you using spring boot for `applicationBatch`?

Comment: Yes component scan is enabled with a base package parent of InternalConfig. Am not using Spring Boot.

Comment: And looks like, i got  what you are trying to say, May be applicationBatch.jar is not doing componentscan for package parent of InternalConfig. I will check that asap and revert back on this post. Thanks a lot for now for your pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot that @NicolasLabrot !! There was specific packages getting scanned for components, which missed my package that contained the InternalConfig class. Its working now.

Comment: If you agree I will submit an answer

Comment: Sure, am good !! Please go on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will manage `InternalConfig` if you import it using `@Import` or have configured component scan with a base package parent of the `InternalConfig` one. `applicationBatch` seems to miss one of this method.

Could you check that ?